# R apply function on nested list elements based on matching nested list names

Tags: r, list, nested

Say I have a named nested list `l` consisting of sub-lists of named numeric vectors, each of length 1:

```
l <- list("L1" = list('a' = 1, 'b' = 2), "L2" = list('a'= 2, 'c' = 1, 'd' = 1))
```

I am struggling to find a way in base R to apply a function such as `sum` for all matching sub-list with similar name (e.g. l$L1$a and l$L2$a whose sum would be 3).
The result from applied using `sum` in `l` would be for instance a named vector `res`:

```
> res
a b c d 
3 2 1 1
```

In (my) real life the list `l` has variable and unknown numbers and lengths of sub-lists `L1`, `L2`, ... , and similar, the names and numbers of the numeric vectors to be summed (`a`, `b`, ...) are also variable and unknown. However, the depth of the list is always as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unnest_wider`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col = l) %>%
    unnest_wider(col) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#      a     b     c     d
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     2     1     1
```

---

Or using `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, do.call(rbind, lapply(l, stack)), sum)
```

Or `rowsum`

```
with(do.call(rbind, lapply(l, stack)), rowsum(values, ind))
```

Or with `tapply`

```
with(do.call(rbind, lapply(l, stack)), tapply(values, ind, sum))
# a b c d 
#3 2 1 1
```

Comment: stack! Never heard of that.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
bind_rows(l) %>%
 summarise_all(~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE))

      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2     1     1
```

Comment: yeah that does it nicely. I am not grateful but was looking for a base R solution

Comment: I don't see an elegant base solution right now but somebody will surely post it :)